# R find and replace text in .xlsx files

Tags: r, excel, replace, find, xlsx

So my task is very simple, I would like to use R to solve this. I have hundreds of excel files (.xlsx) in a folder and I want to replace an especific text without altering formating of worksheet and preserving the rest of text in the cell, for example:

Text to look for:
F13 A

Replace for:
F20

Text in a current cell:
F13 A Year 2019

Desired result:
F20 Year 2019

I have googled a lot and havent found something appropiate, even though it seems to be a common task. I have a solution using Powershell but it is very slow and I cant believe that there is no simple way using R. Im sure someone had the same problem before, Ill take any sugestions.

Comment: Why use R for this? This complicates it immensely because you have to read in XLSX into R (cannot do it natively), change something and then save out to a foreign format again. This would be so much easier to do in VBA which is the proper tool for this. So why R?

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
text_to_look <- 'F13 A'
text_to_replace <- 'F20'
all_files <- list.files('/path/to/files', pattern = '\\.xlsx$', full.names = TRUE)

lapply(all_files, function(x) {
     df <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(x)
     #Or use readxl package
     #df <- readxl::read_excel(x)
     df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {x[grep(text_to_look, x)] <- text_to_replace;x})
     openxlsx::write.xlsx(df, basename(x))
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah, but is there a way to keep the original format in the documents?
Also, it doesnt work for cells where there is additional text. e.g. in a cell with the text: "F13 A 2019" there is no change, do you have an idea to solve this?

Comment: @Davido What do you mean by original format in the documents ? I updated the answer to make it work for partial matching. Can you check that ?